# Make ajax POST and return JSON in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ajax, devise

I'm trying to make an AJAX POST request to one of my routes and return some JSON, but I'm running into an issue where the JSON is not being returned and a page is rendering instead like a GET request. Here is my code:

**View**

```
<%= form_with url: users_add_skill_path, id: "skills-form", format: 'json' do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :skill, placeholder: "Submit your skill" %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit Skill" %>
<% end %>
```

This becomes in HTML:

```
<form id="skills-form" action="/users/add_skill" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="token_hereadnfjahbsdkfjabsd">
    <label for="skill">Skill</label> 
    <input placeholder="Submit your skill" type="text" name="skill">

    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Submit Skill" data-disable-with="Submit Skill">

</form>
```

**Routes**

```
devise_scope :user do
    post '/users/add_skill' => 'users/registrations#add_skill', :defaults => 
{ :format => :json }
end
```

**Controller**

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

respond_to :html, except: [:add_skill]
respond_to :json, only: [:add_skill]    

def add_skill
  @user = current_user
  @user.skills.push(params[:skill])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.json { render json: @user.skills, status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

**Javascript**

```
const skillsForm = document.getElementById("skills-form");
skillsForm.addEventListener('ajax:success', function(res) {
    console.log("added skill"); 
});
```

The 'skill' is being persisted to the database so I know that the request is being made correctly - and if I remove the `:defaults => { :format => :json}` from the routes, and change a few other things in the `respond_to` block (sorry I don't remember exactly what I had changed), the data is persisted the page does not change, so I'm pretty sure the Ajax request is working well, but I don't know how to get the response.

I saw a lot of questions using jQuery ajax() but I'm not using jQuery so I'm not sure what I should be doing. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually realized that I had not included `rails-ujs` in my application.js, and so the request was being made as a GET request and not returning anything. Everything has been solved now, thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your ajax code seems fine but I see some issues in your action `add_skill`. You are trying to push new skills to the existing skills of current user by attribute hash only. Instead build the skill inside the user's skills collection and try to save the user attributes like so:

```
def add_skill
  @user = current_user
  @user.skills.build(skill: params[:skill])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.json { render json: @user.skills, status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

---

- [push(*records)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-3C-3C): Adds one or more `records` to the collection by setting their foreign keys to the association's primary key. The parameter you provided to `push` would result in a `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Skill expected, got 'params[:skill]' which is an instance of String`. Valid way might look like:

> @user.skills.push(Skill.new(skill: params[:skill]))

- [build(attributes = {}, &block)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-build): returns a new object of the collection type that has been instantiated with `attributes` and linked to this object, but have not yet been saved. If you use this approach, then the `respond_to` block would make more sense, as the user skills would not get saved until you call `@user.save`.

Comment: Thanks, do you mean I should create a new model for the skills specifically and just associate them to the user?

Comment: you can do that for sure. But the above solution should work too, no big deal :)

Comment: What is the benefit of doing it the above way as opposed to my original solution?

Comment: its not about benefit. Please have a look at the difference between `build` and `push` in the updated answer above.

Comment: I see. Skill in my instance is not a model, it's just a string right now. So push works fine, but I do have plans to eventually make it into a model so I will keep this in mind, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

when you are using respond_to you should try returning the json with respond_with ,for example

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json


  def show
    @record = Record.find params[:id]

    respond_with @record
  end
end
```

,if its still not working try adding method: :post to your form and try.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this and nothing changed, submitting the form still sends me to a new url that displays the JSON. My form already has method="post" in the HTML.

Comment: what exactly do you want ?can you be clear in your question?

Comment: I would like the JSON to be returned from the AJAX call instead of bringing me to a new page to see the JSON.

Comment: so try removing the respond_to do format and just  respond_with @user.skills.if not try format.js under your previous code

Comment: also try using event.preventDefault(); in your ajax request

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I was looking for the code that initiated the ajax request and I discovered that I didn't have rails-ujs required in my application.js. All i had to do was to add that and it initiated the request successfully. Thanks!

Comment: Alright ,i considered that your ajax request and ujs are correct

Answer (score 0):

First, replace `ajax:success` with `ajax:complete` in your eventListener

You should add `remote: true` in your form html params, then, your request Will respond as the format that you want (default should be as 'JS')

For example: with `format: js`, in your controller  do

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { # TODO block }
end
```

Finally with `send_data`, you can send data to your Ajax callback